# ruby metaprogramming get container class of instance variable from instance method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Imagine we have three classes:

```
class SomeClass

  def container_class
    # ...
  end

end

class Container
  attr_accessor :property
end

class Container2
  attr_accessor :lalala
end

# now I create instances
p = SomeClass.new

c = Container.new
c.property = p
c.property.container_class # => should return Container 

c2 = Container2.new
c2.lalala = p
c2.lalala.container_class # => should return Container2
```

Question:
How can I write method container_class using ruby metaprogramming so it returns class of container (composition) of instance from where this method is called?

You can use metaprogramming only. Container classes should not be changed manually.

Comment: What you ask is impossible. Consider this case: `p = SomeClass.new; c.property = p; c2.property = p`. What would `container_class` do in this case?

Comment: Max, return Container first time and Container2 second time

Comment: @bloodthirsty_ruby_god That makes *no sense*. Now you want to track how many times the method is called and return a different result each time?

Comment: @meagar, I can detect parent class or even class name from mixin. But composition > inheritance :) Why does detecting container class make no sense ?

Comment: @bloodthirsty_ruby_god What do you mean second time? I only called `container_class` once. The essence of the problem was that the same instance of `SomeClass` is contained in two different classes.

Comment: @Max Yes I know, so? I updated my original code to reflect your case too. It is like multiple inheritance but instead multiple composition. But if we suppose that SomeClass instance can only be in one container - that will work for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took this answer from [here](http://rubychallenger.blogspot.com/2011/07/caller-binding.html). Here is a way to get the caller binding:

```
require 'continuation'

def caller_binding
  cc = nil     # must be present to work within lambda
  count = 0    # counter of returns

  set_trace_func lambda { |event, file, lineno, id, binding, klass|
    # First return gets to the caller of this method
    # (which already know its own binding).
    # Second return gets to the caller of the caller.
    # That's we want!
    if count == 2
      set_trace_func nil
      # Will return the binding to the callcc below.
      cc.call binding
    elsif event == "return"
      count += 1
    end
  }
  # First time it'll set the cc and return nil to the caller.
  # So it's important to the caller to return again
  # if it gets nil, then we get the second return.
  # Second time it'll return the binding.
  return callcc { |cont| cc = cont }
end
```

Now, you can define your class `SomeClass` as follows:

```
class SomeClass
  def container_class
    return unless bnd = caller_binding
    bnd.eval "self.class"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is solution, gem for it(that works with different ruby versions): https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller

Answer (score 0):

You can use that, im not using the prettiest way, but you can write a new accessor that injects that methods.

Classes:

```
class Container
  def property=(arg)
    arg.called_from = self.class
    @arg = arg
  end

  def property
    @arg
  end
end

class SomeClass
  def container_class
    @klass
  end

  def called_from=(klass)
    @klass = klass
  end
end
```

Spec:

```
require_relative 'container'

describe Container do
  let(:container) { Container.new }

  it 'passes message' do
    container.property = SomeClass.new

    expect(container.property.container_class).to eq Container
  end
end
```

Comment: Idea is to use metaprogramming. I don't want to write any additional code in Container classes.